# Индексирование записей mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Проект на laravel + docker, для полей `name` и `lot_info`, сущности `lot`, ввел полнотекстовые индекс, вставляю тестовые данные через сидеры и фабрики. Поиск по этим полям выполняю с помощью SQL запроса типа

```
select * from `lots` where MATCH(name,lot_info) AGAINST('сервер' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 20 offset 0
```

Так вот до 100 000 записей примерно, все работало как по маслу, а вот после уже дела ухудшились. Я импортирую за раз по 10000 записей с помощью сидеров. После окончания импорта, примерно минут 5 БД тупит, запрос обрабатывается секунд 5, позже примерно за 500 мс. Я так подозреваю, что в этот момент идет процесс индексирования в фоне, но это не точно. К тому же данные фейковые и часто повторяются.

Так вот хочу поинтересоваться, нормально ли такое явление ? Что же будет когда там будет пара миллионов, по пол дня индексироваться? Подскажите для бд в пару миллионов записей с полнотекстовым индексом нормальная практика, или лучше рассматривать варианты типа elasticsearch ?

Comment: Эксплейн в студию, этот запрос не о чем не говорит. Полнотекстовый поиск сам по себе медлителен

Comment: Вытащите из докера бд, там много теряется из-за виртуализации

Comment: Окей у вас есть телеграм ? Можно вам там написать?Я могу оставить здесь свой, если не хотите светить

Comment: Вам этот чат нужен @phpGeeks, можно и тг

Comment: Тут дело не в этом запросе, любой запрос в эту таблицу сразу после импорта 10 000 записей выполняется около 5 секунд

Comment: Складывается впечатление, что индекс выполняется в фоне, сразу после инморта

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105702/discussion-between-pavel-and-ghost).

Comment: Надо выяснять что происход при импорте нужно метрики смотреть системы и выяснять что именно происзодит